# Android/Java: search the ID of an image inside the device and send it to a client

Tags: java, android, android-image

I saw that in my device (Htc One S), the images are stored on this path: `storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/name_of_file.jpg`

but i'm sure that in other device the path could be different. Well, in my application i have created a server socket and i can successfully send the image to the client. As you see in my code below, i create the path in this mode `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/100MEDIA","IMAG00`26.jpg"  `

that is good for my device but can be wrong for another. So now i have a question...
How can i search the ID or name of a file inside the device or in his SDcard for send it?
Here there is my code for send the image (it work correctly).

```
public class ServerThread extends AndroidApp2 implements Runnable { //dichiaro la classe ServerThread che implementa Runnable

    public void run() {
        try{
            if ( SERVERIP != null){ 
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + ip_address_conversion + ":" + SERVERPORT);                           
                    }
                }); 
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true){
                        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                        handler.post(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                serverStatus.setText("Connected");
                            }
                        });
                        try{
                            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                AlertDialog.Builder connection_alert3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidApp2.this);
                                connection_alert3.setTitle("Connection Incoming");
                                connection_alert3.setMessage("Do you want accept the incoming connection?");
                                connection_alert3.setCancelable(false);
                                connection_alert3.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        alertValue = true;
                                    }
                                });
                                connection_alert3.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                                        alertValue = false;
                                    }
                                });
                                AlertDialog alert = connection_alert3.create();
                                alert.show(); 
                            }
                            });
                            if (alertValue == true){
                            File xmlFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"xmlPhotos.xml");
                            int size = (int) xmlFile.length();
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
                            try {
                                BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
                                buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                buf.close();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            client.getOutputStream().write(bytes, 0, size); 
                            String[] projecton = new String[]{
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                                };
                            Uri image = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(image, projecton,"", null, "");
                            final ArrayList<String> imagesPath = new ArrayList<String>();
                            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                                int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                              do {
                                imagesPath.add(cursor.getString(dataColumn));
                              } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                            }

                            File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/100MEDIA","IMAG0026.jpg");
                            int size2 = (int) photoFile.length();
                            System.out.print("int2: "+size2);
                            byte[] bytes2 = new byte[size2];
                            try {
                                BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(photoFile)); 
                                buf.read(bytes2, 0, bytes2.length);
                                buf.close();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            client.getOutputStream().write(bytes2, 0, size2);

                            serverStatus.setText("Finish the transfer");
                            client.close();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones."); 
                                }
                            });
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            } else{
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can get the list of images inside the gallery this way:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
};

Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cur = managedQuery(images,
        projection,
        "",
        null,
        ""
);

final ArrayList<String> imagesPath = new ArrayList<String>();
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

    int dataColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    do {
        imagesPath.add(cur.getString(dataColumn));
    } while (cur.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have already the list of images with the ID (I created previously an xml file with this informations). I have only to find where is the image with (for example) ID 27 for send it.

Comment: imagesPath contains the complete path to all the image inside the gallery

Comment: Thanks, so after that i have implemented your code i need to search inside the arrayList the image that has the ID that i'm searching right? In this mode i will have the path for send it.

Comment: or you can simply append a where clause to the query to get only the path to your image

Comment: Thanks. Well, i have tried to implement your code in my server socket, but the Cursor seems that it's generating a problem. Here there is the Logcat:
W/System.err(9358): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(9358):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)
W/System.err(9358):  at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1782)
W/System.err(9358):  at com.example.androidappserver.AndroidApp2$ServerThread.run(AndroidApp2.java:157)
W/System.err(9358):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)

Comment: edit your question and post how do you changed the code and the complete logcat

Comment: Done, i added the entire class. Thanks. Do you want the entire logcat of the application or only the alert and error messages?

Comment: AndroidApp2 is the name of the second activity in my application. There are two activities, AndroidApp (the first screen of the app) and AndroidApp2, that is where i'm working.

Comment: is AndroidApp2 an Activity?

Comment: Yes exactly! It's the second activity.

Comment: It is in the my second activity. For give an idea:
public class AndroidApp2 extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
    }

    public class ServerThread extends AndroidApp2 implements Runnable{
        ....
    }
}